# Is there a way to change the layout or theme used when editing an article or module from the frontent

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, front-end

I don't have any problem using the back-end for creating and editing content, but my clients do. I want to provide them with some simpler menu options that are targeted for editing or creating articles in certain categories. I have this working well enough, but when I log into the front end and create a new article, I see some conflicts with the template for the site as well as the editing experience is quite clunky.

Is there a way to assign a different template to these editing experiences?

Comment: I think your question would benefit from some actual context/details so that volunteers know exactly what is going on and what needs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I Feel [sheepish](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sheepish)

All I had to do was go into the **Extensions >> Templates** menu and assign the **Protostar** template to those menu items, and bingo. A template that was pretty much designed to be a front end editor.